# What is the gradle compile dependency for Locating Longitude and Latitude?

Tags: android, android-service, google-maps-android-api-2, android-library, android-location

I want to just import into my project the dependencies from GoogleApi to use location to get longitude and latitude.

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/) which they recommend to use the [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi), but they use eclipse, so I'm using android studio and I just want to add the dependencies for that library.

I know that if I include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` in my build.gradle it will include all services I only need those for locating long and latitude, I don't want to use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` because I want to keep my methods count low.

## UPDATE:

When trying to include:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.0.0'
```

I get

[image]

## UPDATE 2

Got it working with: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `play-services-location` instead of `play-services`.

Note, though, that for inexplicable reasons, `play-services-location` depends upon `play-services-maps`, at least for version 8.1.0. So, you will be pulling in the Maps V2 code as well.

Comment: So I tried including:  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.0.0'` and  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.0.0'`but I get this error: `Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.0.0
Install Repository and sync project; Show in File; Show in Project Structure dialog` ...Please se my updated question for screenshot

Comment: @user912010: Presumably, your Google Repository is out of date. Go into the SDK Manager and update it. BTW, my note about `play-services-maps` is not something that you need to do manually. Gradle supports the notion of "transitive dependencies". Simply requesting `play-services-location` in your `build.gradle` file is all you need, as `play-services-location` itself says that it needs `play-services-maps`.